# Can't insert inkPicture into SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Actually, I am working on a Windows application and I want to add `inkPicture` to capture users signatures to the database. The signature column data type is `varbinary`. The problem is that the record is added to the database but it shows it as null only.

This is what I have done so far:

```
string con = "Data Source=SAIUNIFLOW;Initial Catalog=documentfollowup;Integrated Security=True";

byte[] saveInk = (byte[])axInkPicture1.Ink.Save(InkPersistenceFormat.IPF_GIF, InkPersistenceCompressionMode.IPCM_Default);

cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand();
cmdDatabase.Connection = conDatabase;

//  cmdDatabase.CommandText = "insert into manage (Signature) values(Singature); "; 
cmdDatabase.CommandText= "insert into manage (Signature)" + "values('" +  axInkPicture1 + "'); ";

cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Signature", saveInk);
```

I'm using tablet for getting the signatures but when I click the insert button, I receive that error:

> Cannot insert the null value into column Signature, table doesn't
>   allow nulls.

Hopefully to help me to solve this error.

Comment: Files must go to file storage, not DB.

Comment: I want to add it to the DB  directly for the future reference instead of saving it in a particular storage then upload it again

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I tried using    cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Signature", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = saveInk);

Comment: but it throws exception which says "The sqlParameterCollection is only accepts non-null sqlParameter, not Byte[] objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set the value of `@Signature` parameter. And also try setting the [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the parameter.

Use this instead:

```
cmdDatabase.CommandText= "insert into manage (Signature) values(@Signature);";
var signatureParam = cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Signature", saveInk);
signatureParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually, i have already tried this but the same error

Comment: @Saif, have you checked the value of `saveInk` parameter and the `Parameters` collection of `cmdDatabase`? Maybe somewhere there's a `null` value slipping in.

Comment: Yes i  checked, Everything seem correct. I tried many ways to correct this issue but it didnt work

Comment: Can you open Sql Server Profiler to see what is executed against the database?

Comment: Do you mean tracing the database by using sql server profiler?

Comment: @Saif, yes. Open Sql Server Profiler and trace what statement is executed.

Comment: I checked it, nothing is executed. The tracing is running but nothing is displayed

Comment: @Saif, see the last line from my answer. Try setting the `SqlDbType` property of the new parameter to hint SQL Server that it should be a `byte[]` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot RePierre for your help